# How to accept a POST response (SAML) from a webforms web app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, saml-2.0

How can I make a page (and method within its codebehind) expect a POST response in a webforms  (c#, asp.net) project?

I have a webforms project that needs SAML/SSO implemented in it. I am using the nuget package AspNetSAML in the code below, but this should be a generic issue where the specific library doesn't matter. In my login page's `PageLoad()`, I create and send the SAML request. The problem is: when the user is redirected from the third party IDP back to my page, the SAML Consumer (reply back) URL is not expecting the POST response that the IDP is sending. The browser shows a "405 Http verb used to access this page is not allowed".

That error sounds like the reply back URL in my page is assuming a GET (of default.aspx?) and it needs to assume a POST response. How can I accomplish this in webforms?

```
        LoginSAML.aspx.cs:

        const string samlEndpoint = <third party IDP Endpoint>

        var request = new AuthRequest(
            <EntityID>
            <consumerURL>/Login/SamlConsume" // Assertion Consumer URL
        );

        //redirect the user to the SAML provider
        Response.Redirect(request.GetRedirectUrl(samlEndpoint));
```

I created /Login/SamlConsume/Default.aspx.cs (and Default.aspx.cs) to catch the response when the user is redirected, after login, back from the third party IDP. I think this code is never reached because of the 405 error. The Chrome addon SAML-tracer seems to show that the IDP is sending back a POST when it redirects the user back to my web host (SAML Consumer URL). How should I modify this to accept the POST coming back from the IDP?:

```
    /Login/SamlConsume/Default.aspx.cs:

    namespace myApp.Login.SamlConsume
    {
        public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
            string samlCertificate = @"
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
";

            // Read the SamlResponse data
            var samlResponse = new Response(samlCertificate,Request.Form["SAMLResponse"]);
            .
            .
            .
```